# when using hibernate, difference between run mode and debug mode

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I find that the hibernate would invoke lazy load when in debug mode, while in run mode it not.Why?

in Struts, url contains '.action' for what?

Comment: Usually when running in debugging mode, extra metadata that helps you to debug is added to the produced artifacts. When in release mode, this metadata is not needed and hence it's not added.

Comment: Can you tell me some details about what happened when debug to proxy object that hibernate generates.what's the reason for its lazy loading?

Comment: while in debug mode each request and its things being reloaded, which means each xml file or any other associated file will be reloaded which is not the case when debug mode is disabled.

Comment: How can I tell if the IDE invokes the method or the program itself ?